# "That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers" exception on shared hosting

Tags: asp.net

I have migrated a site based on ASP to a new server, please note that I have virtually no experience with ASP (I primarily work with PHP based sites).  I've managed to work though a few issues I had but there is just one remaining that I unfortunately noticed after completing the migration.  The issue is on this page: http://playvictoria.org/EN/main/involved/join.aspx

I've done several google searches on the "That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers" exception.  From what I understand it's to do with the "trust level" which is likely set to medium as it's shared hosting.  I guess the assembly has to be added to something called the "GAC", but as it's shared hosting I guess I don't have access to that anyway.  I've also read that there is a flag I can set in a .cs file(s) somewhere but I can't find where those would be located.

Any help would be appreciated, keeping in my mind that I'm new when it comes to ASP and Windows servers in general.